# Can a user communicate with a private ethereum network ( Quorum)?

Tags: contract-development, transactions, private-blockchain, quorum

I am up to build a electronic health record system using Quorum. My Project includes Appointments and prescriptions to handled too. I have to make a permissioned network to ensure data privacy. **Can a patient with his public key send a transaction to my private node using my my website's front end?**
 I also want all the nodes to be storing that information as they are trusted health care stakeholders.

Comment: does the patient have his/her private key as well as their public key? and how will you set up your private nodes with respect to CORS domains? Your node configuration will dictate whether anyone can access your network and broadcast new transactions or not, but without details on how yours is set up we can't advise on whether what you're asking is possible on your network

Comment: They should have their private keys to sign transactions as if they have really made an appointment or not. Or allow a doctor to view his health record. ------
Unfortunately, I have not set up any network right now. What i want to achieve is data privacy. So that no one could get Contract/transaction data and current state of the current the contract (as it is possible with ethereum) so i think my use of Quorum is justified.
-------
It would be great if you point me to some learning resources in regard to private node and network set up and Availability of pri./ public keys to participants.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to archive this.

The first way would require every patient to interact with your blockchain directly. This could be archived with a combination of web3, javascript and quorum as a web3-provider.

The second solution would require you to run a node on your web-server and implement the web3 functionality in the backend of your server. So the patient would log in to your web-service and interact with your running quorum node.